# Which tables can be truncated/deleted before doing a full reindex?

Tags: database, reindex, table, delete

I'd like to re-index my whole catalog in magento after finding out some corrupt data exists within a few tables.

This question/post on stackexchange helped me quite a bit in the good direction:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205714/list-of-tables-to-safely-truncate-in-magento

What I'm wondering though, is if there are more tables which can be truncated/deleted safely (which will be repopulated by doing a full re-indexation).

In particular i'm wondering about all of these tables:

- catalog_product_index_eav
- catalog_product_index_eav_decimal
- catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx
- catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp

etc.. (all other catalog_product_index_* tables)

Are those safe to truncate if i'm going to perform a full re-indexation of my catalog? (products & categories)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205714/list-of-tables-to-safely-truncate-in-magento maybe helpful

Comment: Not really, it doesn't mention the catalog_product_index_* tables. Also, i've posted that exact same link in my post. The tables that have been noted in the answer on that question, aren't the only ones that can be truncated for a full reindex. I would like to know which tables can be truncated before doing a full reindex. Thanks for trying to help though.